# Google drive PDF preview scrambled text

Tags: pdf, google-drive

Previewing some PDF files in Google drive shows part of text scrambled:

[image]

Downloading and then viewing this PDF from local machine works fine. I taught that browser PDF plugin is the one to blame, so I have opened local file in browser, but it displays just fine.

Tried this in

- Chrome (v41) and IE11, on Windows 8.1
- FF (v37) on CentOS 6.

Any idea what can be done about this? I would like to avoid downloading every single file to see what's in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading this app (chrome extension) from notablepdf for google drive [Notablepdf](https://www.notablepdf.com/). Then go to your drive and right click the pdf file , click open with and then choose notablePDF. It is one of the popular PDF viewer.

Hope this helps ..

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but NotablePdf is some kind of cloud app which will take the PDF file to it's own server to render a preview. I do not like that.

Comment: @IvanJovovic Yeah.. you are right.

Comment: @IvanJovovic I don't find any other solution .I would recommend contacting  [Google Drive Help Support](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/4431192). The issue is not the problem with you PDF files but it's a problem with the Google docs so they might be able to help you.